# Bootstrap modal is sitting behind backdrop in Vue

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

When I try to add a modal in a component, the backdrop is coming to front and modal is behind it as below. I checked all the position css properties in the parent components. I found nowhere that used `position: fixed, relative or absolute`.

[image]

My code is as below,

```
<template>
    <div
        class="modal p-4"
        id="confirmModal"
        tabindex="-1"
        data-bs-backdrop="static"
        data-bs-keyboard="false"
        aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel"
        aria-hidden="true"
    >
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered p-4 modal-xl">
            <div class="modal-content p-4">
                <div class="modal-body text-center">
                    <p class="my-5">No Images</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import bootstrap from "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js";

export default {
    name: "ConfirmationDialog",

    mounted() {
        this.openViewer();
    },

    methods: {
        openViewer() {

            var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById("confirmModal"), {
                keyboard: false,
            });

            myModal.show();
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Please, help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

Appending modal to body will solve the problem.

So, change the openViewer method as below,

```
      openViewer() {
            const modal = document.getElementById("confirmModal");
            document.body.appendChild(modal);

            var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(modal, {
                keyboard: false,
            });

            myModal.show();
        },
```